# dc.js linechart with time changes in milliseconds

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I am trying to do a line chart with time in millisecons on X-axis. Does not seems to be working. 
I have created a jfiddle. Can someone please have a look when you get a chance .

http://jsfiddle.net/5H3Ay/14/

I am creating the dimension like this

```
var datetimeDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d3.time.format.iso.parse(d.datetime);
});
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the data.  The first data entry specifies a different hour from the rest.

Here is a corrected fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/t5Un3/1/

```
var data = [
    {"id":1,"datetime":"2009-01-26T06:00:00.000Z","peopleVisited":452},
    {"id":2,"datetime":"2009-01-26T06:00:00.200Z","peopleVisited":62},
```

Glad to see that millisecond data does work!